# Navigate From Popover Controller to Another Controller in ios

Tags: objective-c, navigation, uipopovercontroller, pushviewcontroller

Totally i have three View Controller HomeVC,SecondVC and PopupVC.In my project i use the SWRevealView Controller,This swrevealView Controller is Root View View contoller,

In My HomeVC i fix one Button in Navigation Controller While i click that button it shows one Popup View as PopupVC.Below Screen Shows it,

[image]

in the Above Picture the Cart Details is the UIPopoverController of PopUpVC it Shows when the Button is Clicked. Now My problem when i tapped into the List it need to Move the SecondVC but it Getting Error,

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ORDER'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

i have Fixed the Segue From PopupVC to SecondVC, that segue name is "ORDER",How to Navigate From Popover Controller to SecondVC,Help me...

Comment: Basically your 'PopUpVC' is not managed by a `UINavigationViewController`. You should delegate the click event on an item in the List to the `UIViewController` that actually presents your `UIPopoverController`. Understand that the ViewController within the PopoverController is **not** in the same navigation stack as the ViewController that is presenting the popover.

Comment: Your `PopUpVc` is not in a navigation hierarchy. You won't be able to push controllers from here. You can delegate the click event to your `HomeVC` which can push the appropriate controller from there.

Comment: Then what is the Solution to Navigate From PopOver Controller to Another View Controller.Help me